# How to break text column property when a certain width is met?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the text column property since it seems to be convenient but the problem I'm having is that at a certain width I would like for the text columns to "break" and not be there when the screen size is at a smaller width, in this example 50px. I tried to set the column count to 0 for the min width of the screen being met thinking that it would turn my columns into a regular paragraph text format but it doesn't seem to be working when I try to do it in media query but works outside of it? I also tried adding default text thinking that it would fix anything strange going on but nothing changed.

I've included my HTML, CSS and CodePen link. Thank you in advance.

CodePen Link:
https://codepen.io/alexbicycle/details/ExyzdEG

HTML:

```
<section class="section-intro"  id="skills-part-of-page">
    <h2 class="section-intro-title">SKILLS</h2>
        <div class="section-text-columns-container">
              <p class="text-columns">
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
               </p>
         </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.section-text-columns-container{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 21vw;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15vh;
}



.text-columns{
     /*To split text & have side by side*/
    column-count: 2;
     -webkit-column-count: 2;
     column-gap: 5vh;
     -webkit-column-gap: 4vh;
     text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 50px){
  .section-text-columns-container{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 10vw;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  
  .text-columns{
     column-count: 0;
     -webkit-column-count: 0;
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 1%;
    word-break: initial;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `column-count: 0;` try `column-count: initial;`